# Is this a viable case for using a mutable struct?

Tags: c#, struct, mutable

I've been doing some digging through old SO questions about the inherent "evilness" of mutable structs, but as a C# noob I can't tell whether this is an intended use of structs in c#.

So basically I'm learning c# by making a simple text-based dungeon game. I have `Enemy`, `Player`, and `Attack` classes and an `Effect` Struct. Every `Attack` can have an `Effect`, and when the `Player` object attacks an `Enemy` object, it uses its own `Attack` object to calculate damage, and then passes the `Attack`'s `Effect` struct to the `Enemy` where it is added to a list of Effects.

Effect has a duration field, which is decreased every turn until it reaches 0 via this method:

```
public void tick() {
        duration--;
}
```

Every turn, the `Enemy` iterates through the list of `Effects`, calling `tick()` and checking whether `duration` has reached 0. If it has, it removes the struct from the list.

Now is this bad, or is it one of the intended uses of structs? Coming from a java background, I'm used to doing this by `new`ing objects. Is that the way it's supposed to be done in c#?

Comment: Mutable structs can bite you anytime(you seem to have knowledge about it). Make it immutable and let the Tick method return the new struct or simply use a class(but be aware of heap allocation overheads if that's important for you)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel but wouldn't returning the entire struct cost a lot more cpu/memory than simply modifying one of it's fields?

Comment: No. If your struct is small enough, it isn't a problem. If your struct is big enough, then you're not supposed to use struct at all. We have no enough information about the fields of your struct to answer your question. Refer [When to use struct / class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Instead of `duration` you could use some kind of end time that you would compare to some global tick counter. Actually, with two bits of information "start time" and "duration" no information would be lost, so that might be even better if you decide in the future to make the wear off functionality be more complex.